# Show that $u \in H^1(\omega)$ implies $|u(0)|\leq\sqrt{2}\|u\|_{H^1}$

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to show that $|v(0)| \leq \sqrt{2}\|v\|_{H^1}$ we have:

$$
|v(x)| = \left|\int_{0}^{x} v'(t) dt\right| \leq \int_{0}^{x} |v'(t)| dt \leq x^{\frac 1 2} \|v\|_{H^1} 
$$
if you take $x = 0$, it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: What is the domain of $v$?

Comment: $\Omega = (0,1)$

Comment: Why does the last inequality hold? What definition of the $H^1$-norm are you using?
Also, using $x$ as both the integration variable and as a limit is confusing.

Comment: the last one is Cauchy Schwartz applied to the integral between 0 and x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  began by misapplying the fundamental theorem of calculus.  You should have $$|v(x) - v(0)| = \left| \int_0^x v'(t) \, dt\right|\le \int_0^1 |v'(t)|  \, dt$$
so that
$$|v(0)| \le |v(x)| + \int_0^1 |v'(t)|  \, dt$$
for any $x \in (0,1)$.
Now integrate from $0$ to $1$ and apply Holder's inequality:
$$|v(0)| = \int_0^1 |v(0)| \, dx \le \int_0^1 |v(x)| \, dx + \int_0^1 |v'(t)| \, dt = \int_0^1 |v(t)| + |v'(t)| \, dt$$
$$|v(0)| \le \left( \int_0^1 (|v(t)| + |v'(t)|)^2 \, dt \right)^{1/2}.$$
The elementary inequality $(a+b)^2 \le 2(a^2 + b^2)$ gives you
$$|v(0)| \le \left(2 \int_0^1 |v(t)|^2 + |v'(t)|^2 \, dt \right)^{1/2}$$
which is what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your inequality, taking $x=0$ gives the best bound in the world which is *too good* (it ‘proves’ that $u(0)=0$ so of course it’s bounded by the $H^1$ norm.)
2. Hint- you used the FTC wrong. It’s not $\int f’ = f(x)$, it’s $\int
       f’=f(x)-f(0)$.